# Webscrape images and their alt text in Python when you know part of a URL

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I want to webscrape a site, and save some, but not all images to my computer. I want to save about 5,600 images, so doing it manually would be difficult. All of the images urls start with

```
https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/cards/
```

and then some other stuff that is specific to the image. How can I download *only* images that meet that criteria?

Also (sorry this is kind of 2 questions in 1, but its related) how can I save the images alt text as the file name?

Thanks!

Also sorry if this is a dumb question, if you can't tell by the fact that I'm scraping pokemon.com, I'm not exactly a professional.

Comment: Do you have a list of all URLs with images?

Comment: What is *a professional*?

Comment: @JuanC I don't have a full list, I just know (from looking through inspect elements) that they all start with that bit.

Comment: You'd need to get the image URLs as a list or something by targeting their containing HTML element using an HTML parser like Beautiful Soup. After getting those, you could use the PIL module to get each image from their URL and save them to a folder on your computer.

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far.

Comment: once you pull the url, you can use `import urllib.request` `urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, "local-filename.jpg")` to save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```
import requests
import urllib.request

contents = requests.get(url) # Get request to site
data = contents.text # Get HTMl file as text
x = data.split("\"") # Splits it into an array using double quotes as separators (Because all of the image urls were in quotes)  

for a in range(len(x)): # Runs this code for every member of the array

    if 'https://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/cards' in x[a]: # Checks for that URL snippet. (That's not the full URL, each full URL just started with that)

        link = x[a] # If it is, store that member of the array separately to be extracted
        name = x[a+2] # Alt text was always 2 members of the array later, not sure if this is true for all sites.
        path = "/Users/myName/Desktop/Poke/" + name + ".png" # This is where I wanted to store the files
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(link, path) # Retrieved the file from the link, and saved it to the path
```